# TFS with old version TFS change-set history

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, versioning, migrating

I have an on-prem TFS, In that there are too many change-sets are available. Now I'm using Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) for same project, but I want to integrate my on-prem TFS change-sets also at VSTS. It means, If in my on-prem in have change-set from id 1 to 987, after integrate I want whenever any developer check-in any code in VSTS it start from 988, not from 1.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/migration-overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no documented way I am aware of. You have a tiny tiny thin chance going through Microsoft Support by opening a Service Request (i.e. a support ticket)  and hope to touch their heart enough.
If I were you, I would redesign my tools/process to work around this issue e.g. if you use the changeset number in communication prefix with a letter the numbers from the new system.

Answer (score 0):

The 'dirty' solution is to make and commit ~987 non-important changes (add/remove a line etc.) using a script. Afterwards you can destroy those changesets, but you changeset counter is now at the right number.

This absolutely not a pretty solution but I think that you would have more success with it than through the support.